# Simplification PDF of maximum of Exponential random variable and find his Invers

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose we have $N$ exponential random variables $X_i$ a with parameter $\beta$ 
$$P_{X_i}(x)=\beta e^{-\beta x}.$$
We define a random variable  $Z_1$ which is the max of all $N$ exponential random variables $X_i$ as 
$$Z_1=\max\{X_1,\cdots,X_N\}.$$
The the PDF of $Z_1$ is
$$P_{Z_1}(z)=N\beta e^{-\beta z}(1-e^{-\beta z})^{N-1}.$$
Using the binomial theorem, we will have at 
\begin{align}
   P_{Z_1}(z)=&N\beta\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{-\beta z}\binom{N-1}{n}(-1)^n e^{-\beta zn}   \\
   = &N\beta\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1}{n}(-1)^n e^{-\beta z(n+1)}
\end{align}
My question, can we simplify more than that.

What is the PDF of inverse of $Z_1$, $Y_1$ defined by $$Y_1=\frac{1}{Z_1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbb P(Z_1>0)=1$, the distribution function of $Y_1$ is given by
$$
F_{Y_1}(y) = \mathbb P(Y_1\leqslant y) = \mathbb P\left(Z_1\geqslant \frac1y\right) = 1 - F_{Z_1}\left(\frac1y\right),
$$
where $F_{Z_1} = \left(1-e^{-\beta z}\right)^N$. Hence
$$
F_{Y_1}(y) = 1 - \left( 1 - e^{-\frac\beta y}\right)^N,
$$
and the density is obtained by differentiating:
$$
f_{Y_1}(y) = \frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dy} \left[1 - \left( 1 - e^{-\frac\beta y}\right)^N\right] = \beta  N e^{-\frac{\beta }{y}}y^{-2} \left(1-e^{-\frac{\beta }{y}}\right)^{N-1}.
$$

Comment: thank you so much, So we have dirive $f_{y_1}(y)$ how we do simmulation and compar with analitical